# Getting the Shape Group Name Inside a Shape

Tags: excel, vba

When I loop through the GroupItems of **"Full_Banner"**, my code returns the name of each item below in the red squares.

[image]

What I want is for my code to return the name of each item in the blue squares (See below). How can I go about doing this?

[image]

```
Sub Get_Shape_Name()

For Each element In ActiveSheet.Shapes("Full_Banner").GroupItems

    MsgBox element.Name

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Are "Rates" etc. names of *subgroups* of Full_Banner?

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes. "Picture 82" and "Rounded Rectangle 81" were first grouped and named "Rates". And then "Rates", "Outbound Orders", etc. were grouped and named "Full_Banner".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know any method to access names of subgroups. As a workaround, you can ungroup the shape, list all group items and group the shape back:

```
Sub Get_Shape_Name()

    Dim aShape As Shape
    Dim rShape As ShapeRange

    Const sName As String = "Full_Banner"

    Set rShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(sName).Ungroup
      For Each aShape In rShape
        If aShape.ShapeStyle = msoShapeMixed Then
          MsgBox aShape.Name
        End If
      Next
    rShape.Group.Name = sName

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice. I almost posted a more roundabout way but saw this answer. If you get the collection of all individual shapes via `GroupItems`, ungroup the top group, then iterate over the individual shapes, the names of the subgroups that they are part of is accessible using the shape's `ParentGroup.Name` property. Your method is more direct and bypasses the annoying way that `GroupItems` ignores intermediate levels.