# Excel VBA - Connect grouped shapes with connector

Tags: vba, excel

I have two grouped set of shapes I want to link.

I select fine with:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(type_of_milestone).Select`

and can change individual properties etc with 
`'Activewindow.selection.shaperange.groupitems(1).TextFrame.Characters.Text = name_of_milestone.`

But how do I link these with an arrowed connector?  Specifically I want to link the middle of the shape group on the left hand side to the right hand side?

Not sure how to reference a group of shapes as a shape - if this is even possible and directly passing a group of shapes throws an error with

`conn.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect start_milestone, 1
conn.ConnectorFormat.EndConnect finish_milestone, 1
conn.RerouteConnections`

Any ideas?

The macro picks from a series of predrawn groups which are squares, circles and triangles with text beneath, copies it, pastes it, dumps it onto a new sheet,  renames it, then I just want to link one to the next.  Yes, it would probably be better in visio.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro?

Comment: @SJR yes, but it only allows me to connect individual items, not the group or to specify an item in the group.  That's important because I have no idea what the name of the item in the group actually is... though I could drop that out as a string and bung it back in again.  It's just a bit clunky.

Comment: Are you doing the grouping with code? Could you post a screenshot illustrating the sort of thing you want to do?

Comment: Frustratingly I have to work on the clients system which is disconnected from the net and have controls to disallow usb sticks etc. However basically I have a list of milestones which link from Milestone A to milestone B.  Each milestone is a group of two items, a text box and a triangle lets say.  The first group of text and triangle is linked to the 2nd group of text and triangle.  I don't think (having recorded the macro - yes I'd forgotten I could do that) - excel allows me to select groups with connectors, so it's likely it can't do that whatever I do.

Comment: So I need to extract the names of the individual grouped items, then connect those instead.  That's possible, just a faff.   It doesn't appear massively easy either.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387081/getting-the-shape-group-name-inside-a-shape

Comment: I think you can return properties of a group such as position and size so can you position them that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my question, you cannot connect groups, only shapes.

I had a list of milestones I incrementally look through.

The trick was to name a shape in a group with a unique identifier.

`ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.GroupItems(2).Name = id_of_milestone`

Then after I'd drawn all the milestones, run the below to link (The From milestone links horizontally from right side to To milestone on the left)

`for i=1 to number_of_milestones
Current_inc = i + 3 'because of row headers
id_of_milestone = Sheets("Milestones").Range("P" & current_inc).Value 'assign the from value
lookup_milestone = Sheets("Milestones").Range("P" & current_inc).Value 'assign the to value
If lookup_milestone = "" Then 'check to see there actually is a link present, because it can be blank
'do nothing
Else
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddConnector(msoConnectorElbow, 1,1,1,1).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect ActiveSheet.Shapes(id_of_milestone), 4
Selection.ShapeRange.ConnectorFormat.BeginConnect ActiveSheet.Shapes(lookup_milestone), 2
End If`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can draw connectors from groups. Instead I'd like to suggest an alternative solution:
Add invisible shapes where you need them in your shape groups and connect between them.

This is a quick hack to show the concept:

```
CreateHandles ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Group 27"))

Sub CreateHandles(ShapeGroup)
    Dim MaxX As Long
    Dim MinX As Long
    Dim MaxY As Long
    Dim MinY As Long
    Dim Shp As Shape

    Dim LeftHandle As Shape
    Dim RightHandle As Shape

    MaxY = -1000000
    MinY = 1000000
    MaxX = -1000000
    MinX = 1000000

    For Each Shp In ShapeGroup
        If Shp.Top + Shp.Height > MaxY Then
            MaxY = Shp.Top + Shp.Height
        End If
        If Shp.Top < MinY Then
            MinY = Shp.Top
        End If
        If Shp.Left + Shp.Width > MaxX Then
            MaxX = Shp.Left + Shp.Width
        End If
        If Shp.Left < MinX Then
            MinX = Shp.Left
        End If
    Next
    Set LeftHandle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, MinX, (MinY + MaxY) / 2, 10, 10) ' change the 10 to 0 once it works
    Set RightHandle = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, MaxX, (MinY + MaxY) / 2, 10, 10) ' change the 10 to 0 once it works
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(ShapeGroup.Name, LeftHandle.Name, RightHandle.Name)).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Group.Select

End Sub
```

I made the handles bigger here to show the concept. Set the size to 0 once it works. Second thing to fix is the ugly grouping thing at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Sam - I had come to the same conclusion and have extracted the name for the shape, then am looking to link two together... though  I'll explore the look of this as well.